# How To Prevent Binding Refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, tooltip

In my application, i bind the my string property to textblock tooltip.
The problem is the property that i bind is updating too frequently in runtime. So every time when it is updated tooltip refreshes even property value is same.

Following is the code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="0,1" ToolTip="{Binding stringProperty}"/>
```

When stringProperty is updated tooltip refreshes. I want to bind property and i only want tooltip refresh when the updated value is different or maybe some long time after.

Comment: Actually it is the design of the program. It needs to be updated so often because it comes from the live communication. I just want prevent notifying the UI component even binding property changed. Does it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
    public string stringProperty
    {
        get { return _stringProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (!_stringProperty.Equals(value))
            {
                _stringProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("stringProperty");  //Notify UI only if there is new value
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want you can `Compare` string with `Trim` and `CaseInsensitive`

Answer (score 0):

```
private string _stringProperty;
public string stringProperty
{
    get { return _stringProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_stringProperty, value))
        {
            _stringProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("stringProperty");  
        }
    }
}
```

If you use `ReferenceEquals`, it will not throw a `NullReferenceException` if `_stringProperty` is `null`.